# Окно ошибки и знаки вопроса после разметки диска

Tags: ubuntu, установка

Устанавливаю на сервер с флешки ubuntu 14.04.4 LTS скачанный с официального сервера, заливал на флешку программной WinSetupFromUSB 1.6. На сервере стоит raid 1, начинаю установку ubuntu, после разметки диска вываливается окошко ошибки и вместо слов, отображаются знаки вопроса. Нажимаю Ок или крестик, установка начинается заново.

Скрин:
[image: Скрин]

Comment: попробуйте в начале установки выбрать английский язык. В этом случае скорее всего ошибка будет "читаемой" и ее можно будет нагуглить.

Comment: @KoVadim делал и так, тоже знаки вопроса.

Comment: Раз Вы ставите линукс на "сервер", то почему используете gui? качайте серверную инсталляцию.

А также, я бы проверил флешку - при загрузке убунта предлагает пункт, где это можно сделать.

Comment: @KoVadim Спасибо за ответ, проблема была в флешке. Граф. интерфейс устанавливаю для других, не очень знающих консольные команды людей, которые будут администрировать этот сервер.

Comment: графика на сервере - это печаль. Не нужно. просто не нужно.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема оказалась в флешке. Спасибо за совет @KoVadim